# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 48, 48]

Tags: pycharm, opencv, deepface, python

I am trying to detect emotion from camera, but getting ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: [None, 48, 48] error for below code.

```py
import cv2
from deepface import DeepFace
import numpy as np

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

video = cv2.VideoCapture(0,cv2.CAP_DSHOW)

while video.isOpened():
    _,frame = video.read()

    grey=cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(grey,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5)

    for x,y,w,h in face:
        img = cv2.rectangle(frame,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,0,255),1)
        frame = frame.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
        try:
            analyze = DeepFace.analyze(frame,actions=['emotion'])
            print(analyze['dominant_emotion'])
        except Exception as e:
            print("The error is:",e)

    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key==ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
```

I tried to reshape it by adding this line in code (above try: function):
`frame = frame.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)`

but for that i am getting error like:
frame = frame.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 921600 into shape (28,28,1)